# multiple next / previous on same page

Tags: jquery

I have a div containing a number of sections.
I managed to hide all sections except the first one, and add next/previous buttons.

If you click the "next" button it hides the first and show second section, and so on. If you click "previous" it goes back the same way.

The thing is, if I have several such div in my page, one button does the show/hide for all div and not just its own.

And my counter gets messed up, because it's counting all sections in the page and not in each div separately.

```js
$(function() {

  /* add next/previous buttons to all class body_next */
  $(".body_next").append('<button type="button" class="next">Next &#62;</button>');
  $(".body_next").append('<button type="button" class="prev" style="display:none">&#60; Previous</button>');

  var tracker = 1;
  var n = $(".section_next").length;

  /* hide all section_next except the first */
  $(".body_next").each(function() {
    $(".section_next:not(:first)", this).hide();
  });

  $(".next").click(function() {
    $(".section_next:visible").next(".section_next:hidden").show().prev(".section_next:visible").hide();

    tracker++;

    /* show previous button if displayed section is not the first one */
    if (tracker > 1) {
      $(".prev").show();
    }

    /* hide next button if displayed section is the last one */
    if (tracker == n) {
      $(".next").hide();
    }
  });

  $(".prev").click(function() {
    $(".section_next:visible").prev(".section_next:hidden").show().next(".section_next:visible").hide();

    tracker = tracker - 1;

    /* show next button if displayed section is not the first one */
    if (tracker > 1) {
      $(".next").show();
    }

    /* hide previous button if displayed section is the first one */
    if (tracker == 1) {
      $(".prev").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body_next">
  <section class="section_next">
    <p>blah1</p>
    <p>blah1</p>
    <p>blah1</p>
  </section>
  <section class="section_next">
    <p>blah2</p>
    <p>blah2</p>
    <p>blah2</p>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="body_next">
  <section class="section_next">
    <p>blah1</p>
    <p>blah1</p>
    <p>blah1</p>
  </section>
  <section class="section_next">
    <p>blah2</p>
    <p>blah2</p>
    <p>blah2</p>
  </section>
  <section class="section_next">
    <p>blah3</p>
    <p>blah3</p>
    <p>blah3</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, the code snippet was a tad broken, I fixed it for you.

Comment: Why can't you use different classes for next or different ids? because you have used the same class you are getting this issue.

Comment: I do want the same class for everyone. I might have three or one or ten such section in a given page, and several pages likes this. I want the js to work dynamically without feeding it different ID for each situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [solution demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wLsha1x4/1/)

[Version 2](https://jsfiddle.net/wLsha1x4/2/) that puts button in disable state instead of hiding.

You should find the elements like `.section_next` `.prev` `.next` element within the parent `.body_next` element.

Comment: Thanks, that is very close to what I need! However, "next" keeps showing when we reach the last section, and previous keeps showing when we go back to first.

Comment: Updated the link for fixed 'next' and 'prev' button

Comment: @Eloise First, I am not sure if your question was appropriate for this platform. Second, from next time set up a JsFiddle to save us time.